# Please explain this weird response to adb command

Tags: adb, command-line, terminal

```
127|root@android:/ # find / -iname "aaengine"                                  
find: /proc/19619: No such file or directory
```

**I dont know why I got told about some file I never known about when trying to find aaengine file**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite easy: `find /` starts exploring at the file system root (i.e. the very top). So it comes to places you have no access to as normal user, and runs into permission issues. It sees a directory called `/proc/19619` and, knowing this is a directory, wants to traverse into it. But it is not permitted to (most likely the permission of that directory is something like `drwxr--r--`, so everybody can see ("r"ead) it – but only its owner can change into (eXecute)). So your `find` sees it, but can not dive into it.

As you've been running this command as root, permission problems shouldn't be the issue. But taking a look at the directory in question pops up a different answer: `/proc` is storing process information. Below this top-level dir, directories are created using the PID of running processes. So `/proc/19619` stores information on process `19619`. Most likely your `find` was seeing that directory, and at the same moment that process ended; so when `find` finally wanted to dive into, it was gone: `No such file or directory` (not anymore).

Comment: How can this be if I have root access and did the command as root by entering su before the find command?

Comment: See my updated answer. Sorry, I completely missed the `127|root@android`...

Comment: Im wondering that I wasn't using the phone when that process, whatever it was ended.Is this normal?Also I marked your answer as accepted and upvoted it along with your comment to thank you

Comment: It's probably also worth noting that the 'files' in `/proc` aren't actually files: `/proc` just gives programs a way to interact with parts of the system as if they were files.

Comment: Exactly as Dan stated. So yes, perfectly normal: As soon as the process holding PID `19619` ended, `/proc/19619` disappeared to reflect the fact. Expected behaviour, working as designed (and as it should).